# Automatically add text on CVS Commit?

Tags: cvs, hook

I was curious if there was a way to add a hook or something into CVS so that when you commit a text file or into CVS, it will add a certain string at the end of the file?

For example, say something like: "Committed by Joe Schmoe on 03/11/2010"

Comment: You don't want to modify files mid-commit, behind the users back. Tell us what you're trying to do, and we'll tell you how to do it reliably.

Answer (score 3):

The usual way to do something like that is CVS keyword expansion: http://cvsbook.red-bean.com/cvsbook.html#Using%20Keyword%20Expansion

A small drawback is, that you'll have the `$` signs in the file, but many people are used to this convention.